# Postgresql 9.5 or 9.6 for s390x

Tags: linux, postgresql, suse, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

The base version of postgresql available with SUSE Linux V11 SP3 is Postgresql 9.1 - s390x.

But we need postgresql 9.5 or 9.6 version for our zLinux instance deployed on s390x architecture.

I have only found two suitable packages from my search i.e:

- https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/s390x/p/postgresql-server-9.6.1-1.fc26.s390x.html
  (But looks like it's for fedorea, so I am not sure whether it would
  be compatible on zLinux )
- Another one is
  https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-PostgreSQL-9.4-on-SLES11%E2%80%8B
  which tell how to build PostgreSQL 9.4 on SLES11.

Can anybody please point me to a link/tutorial to get it.

Comment: Just compile from source?

Answer (score 2):

This provides you steps on building PostgresSQL 9.6 on the s390x platform. We have tried and tested.

```
git clone https://github.com/postgres/postgres.git
cd postgres/
git checkout REL9_6_2
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
```

For more detailed steps and dependencies follow this link:
https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-PostgreSQL-9.6

Should you face any issues with the same, please comment on this thread.

Comment: Thanks for the procedure. We fixed it long time back. Actually the problem with us was the dependencies required for compiling the postgres source(all the devel libs). We didn't even had those in our SLES repo. But finally we got some and we compiled some and used the same method you have provided